# Getting an unwanted output

Tags: c

In this code, I am experiencing a very frustrating problem.

I have a variable named `moves` which initial value is set to `0`.
I also declared a 2d array named `a` where `i` refers to its row and `j` refers to its column.

My target is to increase the value of variable `moves` until both `i` and `j` values are  equal to `2`.

Now the value of `i` is `0` and `j`, `1`(given by the user), so basically the value of `moves` should be = `3`.

But my output shows the value of `moves` is `5`.

I think there is a problem in any of the condition statements used in this code below,but I can't figure it out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5][5];
    int i,j,moves=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
           if(a[i][j] == 1)
                break;
        }
        if(a[i][j] == 1)
            break;
    }
    
    //somethings wrong in these loops?
    while(i!=2)
    {
        // i = 0
        if(i<2)
        {
            i=i+1;
            moves=moves+1;
        }
        else if(i>2)
        {
            i=i-1;
            moves=moves+1;
        } 
    }

    while(j!=2) // j=1
    {
        if(j<2)
        {
            j=j+1;
            moves=moves+1;
        }
        else if(j>2)
        {
            j =j-1;
            moves=moves+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", moves, i, j);

}
```

---

```
 Participant's output

  5

 Jury's answer
  3
 Checker comment
  wrong answer 1st numbers differ - expected: '3', found: '5'
```

this is a problem of codeforces :https://codeforces.com/contest/263/problem/A

Comment: You should test the `i` and `j` value before entering the first  `while` loop. as pointed by MikeCAT answer, `j` may be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

The second `if(a[i][j] == 1)` in this part

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
       if(a[i][j] == 1)
        break;
    }
    if(a[i][j] == 1)
        break;
}
```

is bad because `j` may be out-of-range here.

It should be `if(j < 5 && a[i][j] == 1)`.

Comment: thanks now its working but i didnt get it:( what do u mean by out of range?